# Who is the character bonded to multiple spren?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

According to [a recent discussion](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/522-dragonsteel-2023), it is possible to bond multiple spren at once:

> Q: Can you have multiple spren at once?
>
> A: This is theoretically possible,
> to have multiple spren. They would both have to agree, which might be
> difficult to get them.... But it is possible. Good question.
>
> Someone may have done that already... It's pretty obvious, too. You
> should be able to figure out who that is from Rhythm of War.

The first person who comes to mind is Venli, but I am unsure if that is who Sanderson is referring to: her odiumspren is trapped within her gemheart by Timbre—so they very much do not agree—and there is not really anything to figure out, since that is mentioned explicitly. On the other hand, no one else really seems obvious, since people like Kaladin and Shallan only seem to have a single bond.

Who is the person referenced here? Is it Venli, or someone else?

Comment: Nale comes to mind

Comment: @Radhil - I know that Nale bonded a highspren to become a Skybreaker. Was he bonded to two? I mean, he basically counts as a spren himself, almost.

Comment: Just thinking out loud of the ones outside the norm. Of course, about the only norms we have are Kaladin and Dalinar. Hoid, Sigzil, Shallan, Renarin, Venli, Nale, the wierd list is long. Is Nightblood Spren?

Comment: @Radhil - Nightblood is apparently a robot spren.

Comment: Shallan had Testament and Pattern, but not at the same time (at least, not yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Shallan**, bonded to Testament and to Pattern

Per Gruuler at https://www.reddit.com/r/Stormlight_Archive/comments/187ruy2/comment/kbgawbx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

> I was at this Q&A, it was very strongly hinted after the question was
> asked that Shallan was who he had in mind, though the hint was open
> ended enough to suggest other possibilities.

From Rhythms of War chapter 115, *Testament*, it appears that Shallan still has a link to Testament even after "killing" her

> And Shallan had not one Shardblade, but two.
>
> ...
>
> For example, she was certain that, during the years between killing Testament and finding Pattern, her powers had still functioned in some small ways.